# ajaxSubmit success callback not fire in IE6

Tags: jquery

I used following code to submit form in JSP,it can fire well in chrome ,but in IE it always open new window for return result,success callback not fire

```
$("#imgform").ajaxSubmit({
    url : '/uc/ws/0.1/user/image/preview',
    dataType : 'text/plain',
    type : 'post',
    success : function(responseText, statusText, xhr, $form) {
        var message = eval("(" + responseText + ")");

        if (message['success']) {
            showPreview();

        } else {
            isAllowPic = false;//
            showErrorDialog('alert', '只支持最大为2M的gif、jpg、png文件', false);
        }

    },
    error : function(xhr) {
        if(xhr.responseText){
            var message = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");
            if (message['success']) {
                showPreview();

            } else {
                isAllowPic = false;//
                showErrorDialog('alert', '只支持最大为2M的gif、jpg、png文件', false);
            } 
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: please show your form. Do you get any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Why bothering with IE6 ? It represents 1.56% of the browsers !!
http://gs.statcounter.com/#browser_version-ww-monthly-201101-201201

You should on the contrary put a red flashy signal inviting them to change browser and not encourage them to keep it !

Together we need to kill the remaining IE6 !!